# Getters And Setters C++

Tags: c++, getter-setter

Ok Guys My Question here is simple.. I want to construct a getter and setter for diffrent value type.. Basically function overloading but with getters and setters.. i tried it like this

```
#include <iostream>;

class Vectors {
public:
    Vectors() {};
    Vectors(int a, int b) {
        x = a, y = b;
    }
    int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    float getX() {
        return (float)x;
    }
    float getY() {
        return (float) y;
    }
     friend Vectors operator+(const Vectors& v1, const Vectors& v2);
     friend Vectors operator/(const Vectors& v1, const Vectors& v2);
protected:
    int x, y;
private:

};

Vectors operator+(const Vectors& v1, const Vectors& v2) {
    Vectors brandNew;
    brandNew.x = v1.x + v2.x;
    brandNew.y = v1.y + v2.y;
    return (brandNew);
};

Vectors operator/(const Vectors& v1, const Vectors& v2) {
    Vectors brandNew(v1.x / v2.x, v1.y/v2.y);
    return brandNew;
}

int main() {
    Vectors v1(2, 3);
    Vectors v2(4, 5);
    Vectors v3;
    v3 = v1 + v2;
    Vectors v4 = v1 / v2;

    std::cout << "VECTOR 4 X : " << v4.getX() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "VECTOR 4 Y : " << v4.getY() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Vector V3 X : " << v3.getX() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "VECTOR V3 Y : " << v3.getX() << std::endl;
}
```

But Obviously it said cant do function overloading and the only type diffrent is return type..

Comment: So the question is? And why not just do the cast *after* you called the getter?

Comment: The question is how you do it.. It tells me the arguments has to be diffrent... @BaummitAugen . Above Code has errors...

Comment: You can't, which according to your last sentence is obvious. Just think about it, if you write `v4.getX()`, how is the compiler supposed to know which getter you want to call? Again, just have the `int` getters and cast their result.

Comment: You want two different (member) functions whose signatures differ only in their return type, is that right?

Comment: Another option: take a look at how the two ++ operators (prefix vs postfix) are different.

Comment: Note that your default constructor leaves the members with **indeterminate values**, not zeroed.

Comment: The `Vectors() {};`. It doesn't do anything at all. Btw. the semicolon isn't needed here.

Comment: Yeah your right.... Oh well that was like 2 hours ago.. now im watching about inheritance @Cheersandhth.-Alf ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXs3j-lF8JE&index=33&list=PLS1QulWo1RIYSyC6w2-rDssprPrEsgtVK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to overload a function without changing the arguments that I'm aware of. You need to either change the function name (call it getXFloat() or something) or just to the cast after calling the function like:

```
float the_x_value = static_cast<float>(vec.getX());
```

I would go for the second option.

Comment: In C++ I recommend using static_cast<float> instead of C-style casting.

Comment: You're right -- thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Of course you're not using enough templates. Templates solve problems in C++. Use them. Love templates.

```
struct YeeTemplates {
    float F;
    template <typename T>
    T getF() { return F; }
} y;

float f = y.getF<float>();
int i = y.getF<int>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't overload methods based on return type.

You can overload functions on it's input paramaters.

For example:

```
void fun1(int a,char b);
void fun1(float a,char b);
void fun1(float a,int a,char b);
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm

Answer (score 0):

Another option you have is to not return the result as the return value. Instead:

```
...
void getX( float& result) const {
    result = static_cast<float>(x);
}
void getX( int& result) const {
    result = x;
}
...
```

Just adding to the list of options, not saying this is the best solution.